# Both italic and normal text in a html (Or asp.net) textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

How can I do this by using javascript? For example, I have a text Axxxxxx that should be displayed in a text box. If the first text is A, then the first text style is normal style and the following text style is italic. A*xxxxxx*

Otherwise the text is all in italic in a text box *xxxxxx*

Is it possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say text box, do you mean `<textarea>` or `<input type="text" />`? `<textarea>` doesn't support styles.

Comment: `<textarea>` does support CSS styles.

Comment: @Derek - you're both right. I think Scott meant that `<textarea>` and `<input type="text">` elements don't support different styles applied to different parts of their text. (CSS selectors like `:first-letter` don't seem to work on textareas and inputs.)

Comment: What I want the textbox should be <input type="text" />. It seems that making this kind of text box is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can get italic and bold letters in textarea by following code

```
<textarea style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"></textarea>
```

May this will help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Italic and bold</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for something like this is to investigate the `contentEditable` property, but I've never used it myself.

All I know is, you can't have text of different styles inside the same textbox. Mostly because the text isn't even a node, it's an attribute value.

Comment: May be sth like jquery html editor or ajaxcontrolkit - htmleditor can help here. But I dun know how to use that technique and simply add a text box to my page, just like adding <input type=text" id="txt" /> or with some css/javascript